# C++ version of VBA's with command for more elegant code

Tags: c++, vba, optimization

I am writing this in c++:

```
returner.token[0].type = "a";
returner.token[0].fQF = "b";
returner.token[0].val = "c";
returner.token[0].pos = "d";
returner.token[0].emit = "e";
```

In VBA, you can write something similar to this:

```
with returner.token[0]
    .type = "a"
    .fQf = "b"
    .val = "c"
    .pos = "d"
    .emit = "e"
end with
```

Is there similar functionality built into C++?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for references.

```
auto& r = returner.token[0];
r.type = "a";
r.fQF = "b";
r.val = "c";
r.pos = "d";
r.emit = "e";
```

Other mechanisms that can help you here include defining an appropriate constructor, and using a braces initializer list (if appropriate).

There is no C++ statement like Visual Basic `with`: it just isn't necessary, and a reference does the job with less ambiguity.